# Is there a way to download images that I create with the matplotlib pyplot library in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I feel like this is probably a basic question, but I need to create a database of ellipses with random dimensions for a project. I'm doing the following code right now in Google Colab:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image 

from skimage import color

for i in range(2):
  img = np.full((64,64,3), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
  center_x = np.random.randint(30,45)
  center_y = np.random.randint(30,45)
  major_axis = np.random.randint(1,9)
  minor_axis= np.random.randint(1,9)
  angle = 0
  B = 0
  G = 0
  R = 0
  ellipseCoords = [img, (center_x,center_y), (major_axis, minor_axis), angle, 0, 360, (B,G,R), -1]
  a = cv2.ellipse(img, (center_x, center_y), (major_axis, minor_axis), angle, 0, 360, (B, G, R), -1)
  plt.imshow(a)
  a.shape
```

The above code creates and graphs two ellipses as intended. I'm going to end up needing about 64-100 for the final thing, so individually saving the images seems very time-consuming. Worse comes to worse, I'll do that, but I would prefer using a computerized way.

Is this possible to do? I can't seem to find anything that helps...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib's `savefig` function (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) at the end of each iteration like so:

```py
for i in range(n):
    # generate elipse

    plt.imshow(a)
    plt.savefig(f'elipse_{i}.png')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely give that a try.